# the expression of the coefficients of the power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D_{R}$={$|z| < R$}, z is a complex number, and let f(z)= $\Sigma a_{n}z_{n}$ be analytic in $D_{R}$. Let u(z)=Re(f(z)), then prove for all n and 0<r<R,
$a_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi r^{n} } \int_{0}^{2 \pi} u(re^{it})e^{-int}dt$
I know that from the normal method I can get $a_{n}=\frac{1}{2 \pi r^{n} } \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(re^{it})e^{-int}dt$. So the next step is to calculate $2\int_{0}^{2 \pi} u(re^{it})e^{-int}dt=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(re^{it})e^{-int}dt$ Then we know that $u=(f+\bar{f})/2$. So $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \bar{f}(re^{it})e^{-int}dt=0$ I'm not sure how to prove this equation.

Comment: Should $z_n$ be $z^n$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1315771/42969

Comment: @mrsamy Thank you! It should be $z^{n}$

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your help!